# How to instruct my program to display error message once in Java

Tags: java

My project requires users to enter time in a 12-hour format only. 
I believe what I did is logical-error and could not figure out what I did wrong.
When the User entered a none 12-hour format, the program should output an error message once, however, mine outputted it twice.

```
My Program output the following (Which is not preferred):

To exit the program, enter 'quit'. 
Enter Hour: 
111
Enter Minutes: 
23
Enter am/pm: 
pm
PROGRAM: Not a valid time, please re-enter
PROGRAM: Not a valid time, please re-enter
USER: 111:23pm
Enter 'y' to continue:
```

```
The correct output should be as follows:

PROGRAM: Not a valid time, please re-enter <--- should Only display once
USER: 111:23pm
```

Here's my Source code:

```java
public void setAmm(String indicate) {
    try {
        if(indicate.equalsIgnoreCase("am") && getHour() < 12) {
            System.out.println("PROGRAM: Good Morning!");
        } else if(indicate.equalsIgnoreCase("pm") && getHour() < 6) {
            System.out.println("PROGRAM: Good Afternoon!");
        } else if(indicate.equalsIgnoreCase("pm") && getHour() > 6 && getHour() <= 8) { 
            System.out.println("PROGRAM: Good Evening!");
        } else if(indicate.equalsIgnoreCase("pm") && getHour() > 8 && getHour() < 13) {
            System.out.println("PROGRAM: Good Night!");
        } else if(!(getHour() > 0 && getHour() < 13)) {
            System.out.println("PROGRAM: Not a valid time, please re-enter");
            return;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("PROGRAM: Not a valid time, please re-enter");
    }
}


public String setTime(int hour, int minutes, String indicate) {
    setHour(hour);
    setMinutes(minutes);
    setAmm(indicate);

    return String.format("USER: %2d:%2d%s", getHour(), getMinutes(), indicate);
}
```

My Set and Get methods

```
    public MyTime()
    {
        this.setTime(hour, minutes, indicate);
    }


    public void setHour(int hour) 
    {
        this.hour = ( (hour>0 && hour <=12) ? hour : hour); 

    }


    public int getHour() 
    {
        return hour;
    }


    public void setMinutes(int minutes) 
    {
        this.minutes = ( (minutes>0 && minutes <=60) ? minutes : minutes); 
    }



    public int getMinutes() 
    {
        return minutes;
    }
```

How i Invoke it in Main:

```
    System.out.println("Enter Hour: ");
            hour = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Minutes: ");
            minute = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter am/pm: ");
            indicate = keyboard.next();

            MyTime time = new MyTime();
            System.out.println(time.setTime(hour,minute,indicate));

            System.out.println("Enter 'y' to continue:");
            reply = keyboard.next();
```

Comment: you don't show enough of your code. As far as we know, this code is never called. You'll need to show the way you call it and the parameters you pass

Comment: I tried to create a [mcve] from the code you posted: https://ideone.com/2QWn1x. The code worked fine. Please create a mcve so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: where is your setHour() and setMinutes() method?

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for pointing it out. This is my first time posting a question.

Comment: `this.hour = ( (hour>0 && hour <=12) ? hour : hour);` This bit of code is completely useless: the ternary operation checks if "hour" is between 1 and 12, and then returns "hour" either way. Also, please do not ever use ternary operators this way, it will confuse everybody reading your code, including yourself.

Comment: Put a debugger breakpoint everywhere that message could come from (I can see two possible places in your code, although there might be more), and then look which one(s) of them are called. I strongly suggest doing this for yourself, because finding your own mistakes is an important skill and StackOverflow will not be able to do it for you every time.

Comment: @Taschi Thank you Taschi, now I know there such breakpoints that I can toggle to debug code, I will learn more about it! :)